# common-account line read order

Tags: pam, ldap

My authentication is centralized in a LDAP. I've one login system who is working without any ldap so it's present in my `/etc/passwd` file.
This my common-account file in pam.d directory.

```
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 10000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

I've no problem with this but I would like to know if this file is ordered well because on some documentation  the pam_ldap.so configuration line is the first.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be correct (except you should probably be using `auth` and not `account`). Let's take each line one by one:

```
auth     required      pam_unix.so
```

Here, you enter the chain through `pam_unix` (standard password authentication). This module is `required` which means that whatever happens, the chain will continue further down. However, if this module fails, the chain will be marked as failed, and the user is likely to be denied access eventually.

```
auth     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 10000 quiet
```

This line checks the requested UID. If the module succeeds (the user ID is below 10000), the chain will stop because the module is `sufficient`. However, this does not change the mark set by the previous `required` module: if UNIX authentication had failed, the chain will end with a failure, even if `pam_succeed_if` is successful.

```
auth     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
```

If we are here, `pam_succeed_if` must have failed (because it did not put an end to the chain as a `sufficient` module). This means that we are above UID 10000 (which I believe is the threshold you set for LDAP users). The behaviour of this module is a bit more detailed:

- If it succeeds, the chain is marked as successful (`ok`). This will counter the result of the UNIX module and bring the chain back into a successful state.
- If the user is unknown to the LDAP server, the module will be ignored. Your chain's result will be that of `pam_unix`.
- In all other cases (`default`), the module marks the chain as failed (`bad`), whether UNIX succeeded or not.

Finally, you have a dummy module:

```
auth     required      pam_permit.so
```

This module succeeds everytime. It is used to set the state of the chain to *success* if no module has acted upon it earlier. It is never your case though.